# MemoryError in zlib decompressor / zipfile

Tags: python, zlib

I am using zipfile module to unpack a zip archive. For one of the files, the process fails with MemoryError exception on line 682 of `zipfile.py`:

```
data = self._decompressor.decompress(
    self._unconsumed,
    max(n - len_readbuffer, self.MIN_READ_SIZE)
)
```

The values of the variables are quite normal (`n == MAX_N`, `len_readbuffer == 0`, `MIN_READ_SIZE == 4096`), so the parameter passed to the decompressor is MAX_N or `1 << 31 - 1`. All other files in the zip archive are extracted without problems.

I have tried running `ZipFile.testzip()`, it returns `None`. Other tools (Total Commander, 7zip) can read and extract the file in question without problems.

The archive was produced by our proprietary packing tool, but all other archives and their content seem to be OK.

I am using Python 2.7.11 on Windows.

I would be grateful for any suggestion what to try next.

For the record, this is the code I use to access the zipfile:

```
def GetFileContentFromZip(file_source, f):
    s = ''
    with file_source.open(f) as fo:
        s = fo.read()
    return s
```

Where `file_source` is the ZipFile I have already opened and `f` is the path to the file I am trying to get.

Comment: To ask the obvious question... how big is the file you're trying to extract? Is there any way you can restructure the program to read and process it incrementally rather than `read()`ing it all in at once?

Comment: the file has 350MB, and it is the biggest file in the archive, but there are others almost as big, that do not throw the error. The ZipFile read() method does not have a length parameter -- it is supposed to give you the whole file (or that's the way I understand it)